# How can I get data from a specific row to the rest of my table with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would know how can I get a column for example from the Tenth line to the last of my table ?
like this :

```
Model::where('foo', 'bar')->fromTo(FROM_TENTH_ELEMENT, TO_THE_LAST)->get()->toArray();
```

I know you can do a trick like this

```
Model::where('foo', 'bar')->take(count(Model::all()))->skip(10)->get()->toArray();
```

But it's too hard...

**EDIT**

Like elfif said using count method, the best solution.

```
Model::where('foo', 'bar')->take(Model::count())->skip(10)->get()->toArray();
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have a route that have to retrieve 183 columns and only 10 of these data are visible on your screen. Sometimes people don't scroll if these find what they are looking for directly.

Then I would load only the first tenth elements, and if he scroll I load the rest. A kind of infinite scroll.. but I already use infinite scroll with angularjs. the is just to prevent huge traitements of 183 elements when the page is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer depends on how do you want your table to be sorted at that time.
Anyway here is what i would do

> Model::where('foo', 'bar')->skip(20)->limit(10)->orderBy('id')->get()->toArray()

This will get 10 rows past the 20 first rows with the table ordered by id

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yes that's what I do for now.. Thank you.
But I'm looking for a native method with possibility to limit to the rest of ma table's lines.. And skip alone is not working

Comment: If i have understood your question, combining skip and limit all together should do the tricks .... BTW what do you mean by "native method" ? Do you intend to code the Sql Query all by yourself ?

Comment: I know you understood.
And this works like a charm. 
But In my case I find it to huge because I have to Make two Requests, in one when I count the number of lines in my table and i get my data.

Comment: So your complain is about speed because you do two requests and you would like to do only one ? If you need the row count before doing the "skip and limit" request there is unfortunatly no other way. Anyway Model::count() is a really light request  for a database even if the row number is really big

Comment: Ok my mistake.
Thanks I Didn't know the count() method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way coming to my mind is to fetch all items from your table first.

Then iterate over the result and eliminate the first ten items in laravel